# Webcomponents Polymer elements are not visible

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to use PolymerElements in my project, have imported all libraries, but there is nothing on the screen (in the console in the DOM-tree all elements are in place, so they are simply not visible at the moment).

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

Here are all imports

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">

<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
```

DOM-module with HTML

```
<dom-module id="main-component">
  <template>
    <style>

    </style>

    <app-drawer-layout>
      <app-drawer>
        <app-toolbar>
        </app-toolbar>

        <paper-menu>
          <paper-icon-item></paper-icon-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </app-drawer>

      <app-header-layout>
        <app-header>
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-tabs>
              <paper-tab>My first tab!</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <iron-pages>
          <div>One</div>
          <div>Two</div>
          <div>Three</div>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>

  </template>
```

And the script

```
  <script>

    class MainComponent extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'main-component'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'main-component'
          }
        };
      }

      ready() {
        super.ready();
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MainComponent.is, MainComponent);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Where bower_components elements located ? `../../bower_components` or `./bower_components` acording to above your element. Because polymer-element.html and others seams located different path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using a [deprecated `paper-menu`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu#paper-menu).
Not sure if this happens with your build but according to the [readme](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/blob/master/README.md) it'll force you to use Polymer 1.x which does not understand class based syntax.

Try starting new with fresh Polymer Starter Kit and upgrade to [`paper-listbox`](https://github.com/polymerelements/paper-listbox).
I did that with your code and got your `tab` element on screen (I had to fix your paths though).